# Отображение изображения через ссылку в базе данных

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot

У меня есть база данных MySQL, в таблице я храню ссылку на изображение которая хранится на AWS S3. Это изображение, в базе данных, привязано в конкретному пользователю который зарегистрировался.

Мне нужно сделать отображение изображений (по 3 фото в ряд), ссылки которых находятся у меня в БД. То есть когда я добавляю ссылку, надо чтоб это изображение добавлялось на страницу.

В программе использую Java, Spring Boot, Thymeleaf, HTML(для отображения страниц).

Заранее всем спасибо!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сущность Image

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "image")
public class Image {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;
@Column(name = "image_link")
private String imageLink;

public Image() {
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Image{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", imageLink='" + imageLink + '\'' +
            '}';
}}
```

Comment: "В программе использую Java, Spring Boot, Thymeleaf, HTML" - как используете? Пример, что не получается?

Comment: @Bakhuss это я в общем описал, извините если слишком обобщенно. Точнее я создавал сущности которые у меня есть в бд. в данном случае я создал только сущность Image, а дальше я не знаю как отобразить изображения ссылки на которые у меня хранятся